# div:hover issue on IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have an icon: when I click on it, an other div, which was hidden,  appears just upside. But only when we hover the icon. It works perfectly on FF and Chrome, but on IE10, when you hover the div hidden, it makes it appear...

Here is the html:

```
<div class="enveloppe_abo" id="enveloppeabo_92">
    <li class="abo">
        <img src="/images/avatars/femme.gif" class="avatar_40">
    </li>
    <div class="bulle_abo">
        <div class="avatar_abo_bulle">
            <img src="/images/avatars/femme.gif" width="68" height="68">
        </div>
        <div class="supprabo" id="supprabo_92" alt="Remove subscription" title="Remove subscription"></div>
        <div class="texte_abo_bulle"><a href="http://steph.toto.com" target="_blank" class="lien_bulle">steph.toto.com</a>
            <br>
            <br>Blog de blog blalala et oui de deux trois et quatre informations
            <br>Encore une info et oui bien s&amp;ucir...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.avatar_abo_bulle{
float: left;
position: relative;
height: 68px;
width: 68px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}
.texte_abo_bulle{
    margin-left: 90px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.enveloppe_abo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  z-index:11;
}
.enveloppe_bulaut {
    position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.bulle_abo, .combulle {
border: 1px solid #909090;
bottom: 100%;
color: #fff;
display: block;
left: -114px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
opacity: 0;
padding: 20px;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
min-width: 250px;
-webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
-moz-transform: translateY(10px);
-ms-transform: translateY(10px);
-o-transform: translateY(10px);
transform: translateY(10px);
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
transition: all .25s ease-out;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #c9c9c9 2%, #606060 53%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(2%,#c9c9c9), color-stop(53%,#606060)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#c9c9c9 2%,#606060 53%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#c9c9c9 2%,#606060 53%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#c9c9c9 2%,#606060 53%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#c9c9c9 2%,#606060 53%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#606060',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.bulle_abo{
    min-height: 90px;
}
.combulle{
    margin-left: -36px;
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.bulle_abo:before, .combulle:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.bulle_abo:after, .combulle:after {
background: url(/themes/glace_et_ombre/images/flbas.png) no-repeat;
bottom: -20px;
content: " ";
height: 20px;
left: 144px;
margin-left: -13px;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
}

.enveloppe_abo:hover .bulle_abo, .enveloppe_bulaut:hover .combulle{
    min-height: 90px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  display:block;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}

/* IE can just show/hide with no transition */
.lte8 .enveloppe_abo .bulle_abo, lte8 .enveloppe_bulaut .combulle{
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .enveloppe_abo .bulle_abo, lte8 .enveloppe_bulaut .combulle {
  display: block;
}
a.lien_bulle:link, a.lien_bulle:active, a.lien_bulle:visited {
    color: rgb(0, 78, 194);
text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 18px;
    -o-transition:.3s;
-ms-transition:.3s;
-moz-transition:.3s;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
transition:.3s;
}
a.lien_bulle:hover {
    color: rgb(228, 235, 255);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
```

The demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/

Any solution for this please? :-(

Comment: As far as I can tell, the fiddle works the same in IE10 as it does in Chrome -- the box pops up for both of them

Comment: The issue is that the popover activates on a too-large area in IE10.

Comment: Yes, both IE and Chrome the div popup, this is not the problem. The problem is if you hover the mouse on the hidden div, it appears. Try to put the mouse cursor 100px upside the picture, in IE it make appear the div, in Chrome not. It must not appear if we put the mouse elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.enveloppe_abo:hover .bulle_abo, .enveloppe_bulaut:hover .combulle{
```

To

```
.abo:hover + .bulle_abo, .enveloppe_bulaut:hover .combulle {
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/1/)

You were selecting the entire container, not just the image

**Re-Edit**

You must also add `display:none` to `.bulle_abo` to retain the same functionality. [**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/4/)

```
.bulle_abo, .combulle {
    // A bunch of lines
    display: none;
    // A bunch more lines
}
```

**Another Edit**

To add the animation back I created a CSS3 animation along with browser prefixes. [**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/6/)

To call it

```
animation: appear .25s linear forwards;
```

The keyframes for it

```
@keyframes appear {
    0% {opacity:0; transform: translateY(10px);}
    100% {opacity:1; transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

Comment: The problem it that solution is that the hover does not stay... You can click on links on the hover div, and if it disapear when you go on it, you can't access the data inside...

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Internet explorer v10

Comment: This is the latest version, it is up to date... But the problem remains even if it is not... And I can't ask users to upgrade their browser to be able to visit the website... I can ask to have the v10, but not more...

Comment: CSS2 selectors go back to IE 7, [see this page for a full support list](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2). CSS3 selectors (you used them already, not just me) only go back to IE 9, [see the full support list here](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)

Comment: That isn't relevant to this question though

Comment: What problem? That people don't upgrade their browsers?

Comment: No, that there is a problem in my code, I need one which is working with all version 10 of IE (which accepts css3)

Comment: Your edit http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/3/ doesn' work... Still same problem when you hover the hidden div with IE 10 :-(

Comment: Sorry, the last edit was done hastily. The re-edit fixes the problem in my IE10

Comment: It works! But I just change the line `.abo:hover + .bulle_abo, .bulle_abo:hover, .enveloppe_bulaut:hover .combulle {` in my css and it doesn't work on my site. Do you have changed something else?

Comment: ok, I've found it. But with your solution, we have lost the animation (when hovering the icon, the div appears while going up slowly...

Comment: I've checked the fiddle, but I have no animation... The animation is the movement of the div from bottom to top while appearing

Comment: We are speaking about http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/5/ correct?
In this link it doesn't work in IE, chrome and FF... The div doesn't move up/down, only fade in fade out...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/5/ Works in both Chrome and IE10 for me when I hover over the image. I don't have FF to check

Comment: And the div is moving slowly from the bottom to the top? (please see http://jsfiddle.net/YRwCt/)

Comment: Ah, you mean the 10px animation. I added it back http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/YRwCt/6/

Comment: Yes! That's it! :-) Thanks. Finaly I've made 2 css files and I put it depending of the browser detected.

Answer (score 2):

The Fiddle works. Maybe you have to add the doctype at the beginning of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```